# SqlConnection property in a custom asp.net database component

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im making a few static classes to avoid rewriting the same code multiple times and to keep all the database related methods in the same place.

the class look like this:

```
public static class Database_dbSurvey
{
 public static DataSet GetQuestionari()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default_connection"].ConnectionString);
        string query = "[admin].[SRV_Categorie_Lista]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //GetDataSet use the SqlDataAdapter.fill() method
        return Utils.GetDataSet(cmd);
    }

    etc.... (others similar methods)
}
```

I want to reduce the code and I want to make it more "object oriented", so I started by making a property for the SqlConnection (which is the same for every methods of this class).

```
private static SqlConnection connection
    {
        get { return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default_connection"].ConnectionString); }
    }
```

The problem is that it works perfectly with SqlDataAdapter.fill(), till I use a method like this:

```
using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Now, the next usage of the connection will throw the "not istanziated" exception and I can't understand why.

what is the correct way to define the connection property?

p.s.
if you have other suggestion on improving the code it will be higly appreciated

**EDIT:**
I still dont get it why the "new" keyword do not create another istance of the SQLConnection everytime I call it.
however I made some changes to make the code safer:

```
 private static string connection_string
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection_dbPrysmianSurvey"].ConnectionString; }
    }

 public static DataSet GetQuestionari(string username)
    {
        string query = "[dbo].[SRV_Test_Lista]";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            return Utils.GetDataSet(cmd);
        }
    }
    public static int CreaTest(string ID_questionario, string username)
    {
        string query = "[dbo].[srv_test_genera]";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_categoria", ID_questionario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_utente", username);

            connection.Open();
            return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```

But considering the fact that I have 40-50 methods it's still is a pain to rewrite the same lines 40-50 times, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `using` keyword in your case.

It will dispose the connection after that `using`'s scope is complete by calling `SqlConnection.Dispose` method.

`using(connection) {...}`'s equivalent -

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I dont get it... the point of the NEW keyword isn't to create a NEW connection everytime?   I thought that even if I dispose the connection, the next time I use the property, the get would make me a new SQLConnection. So you are telling me that im now using the same connection for EVERY user? it means that I only create one connection and never actually close it?

Answer (score 0):

As @Parag Meshram mentioned, using keyword disposes everything inside itself when completed.

There are two ways I can suggest:

(1) Don't make connection a static method

> private SqlConnection connection() { get { return new
>   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default_connection"].ConnectionString);}
>   }

then use it like

> SqlConnection newConnection = connection();
>
> using (newConnection) { ... }

Or

(2) Keep your static method as is but use it like this:

> try {
>       connection.Open();
>       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); } catch {
>       throw; }

This way, your connection is not disposed.

I had the same problem a year ago and that's now I resolved it, using method (2).

Comment: I cannot declare a variable NON-static within a static class

Comment: Definitely. You will have to create a non-static class for that. What I did was to separate functions as well. SqlConnection was in its own class, User methods in their own class, Clients' methods in their own as well, etc. That way you could use Users.Create() and Clients.Create() to mean different things. Both localizing the non-static connection.